# How to get private IP of server?

Tags: networking, docker

I need to get the private IP of my server so that I can pass it to an env var in my docker container.

I'm trying to use the script `ip r s 0/0 | awk '{print $3}'` which gives me the ip `14x.9x.6x.1`. The public IP of my server is `14x.9x.1xx.1xx`.

I have a forward proxy server running on port `8080`.

`curl example.com --proxy localhost:8080` works

`curl example.com --proxy 14x.9x.1xx.1xx:8080` works (public IP)

`curl example.com --proxy 14x.9x.6x.1:8080` doesn't work (supposed private IP)

I've already googled "host to use host IP in a docker container" which is how I arrived at the `ip r s 0/0 | awk '{print $3}'` solution which I don't get why is not working.

Comment: Try `hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'` ?

Comment: @Liso he is getting an IP ;-) 2nd line. I misread it too :D so there is something different going on. "private ip" ... I would alsways use localhost. That NEVER changes. 14x.9x.6x.1 is NOT an internal IP, You need 10.* or 192.*  You probably have a misconfiguration somewhere  but is it difficult to tell

Comment: I can't use localhost because that doesn't work inside a docker container. `hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'` gives me the public IP